# How should I modify the restartGame function to make it work properly?

Tags: javascript, game-development

So I have a snake game that is based on Kenny Yip Coding tutorial (https://youtu.be/baBq5GAL0_U). The code is given down below. My restartGame function does not work well as it doesn't update the board properly on the first call. When called 2nd time it works well.
I've tried using clearInterval but then the game freezes totally.

```
//board
const blockSize = 25;
const rows = 20;
const cols = 20;
const board = document.getElementById("board");
const ctx = board.getContext("2d"); 
const borderClr = 'black';
const boardClr = 'green';

//snake
let snakeX = 5 * blockSize;
let snakeY = 5 * blockSize;


let snakeBody = [
    [snakeX - blockSize, snakeY],
    [snakeX  - 2 * blockSize, snakeY],
];

const snakeClr = 'blue';

// starting velocity
let velocityX = 0;
let velocityY = 0;

// current direction (only used to prevent changing direction multiple times with in one "tick")
let currentDirection = null;

//food
let radius = blockSize / 2;
let foodX;
let foodY;
const foodClr = "red";

let gameOver = false;

//score
let score = 0;
let gameSpeed = 100;

let intervalID;

// This function executes after the window has loaded
window.onload = function() {
    // Initialize the game board and set its dimensions
    board;
    board.height = rows * blockSize;
    board.width = cols * blockSize;
    // Initialize the canvas
    ctx;
    
    // Place the food on the board
    placeFood();
    // Listen for user input to change the direction of the snake
    document.addEventListener("keyup", changeDirection);
     // Set the update function to execute every 100 milliseconds
    intervalID = setInterval(update, gameSpeed);
    alert("Use arrow keys to move the snake.");
}

// This function updates the game state every time it is called
function update() {
    // If the game is over, stop updating
    if (gameOver) {
        return;
    }

    // Update the score display
    scoreTxt.textContent = score;
    
    // Clear the canvas and draw the board and food
    ctx.fillStyle= boardClr;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, board.width, board.height);


    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc( foodX + blockSize/2, foodY + blockSize/2, radius, 2 * Math.PI, 0, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = foodClr;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle = borderClr;
    ctx.stroke();

    // If the snake eats the food, increase the score and add a new segment to the snake
    if (snakeX == foodX && snakeY == foodY) {
        score += 1;
        snakeBody.push([foodX, foodY]);
        placeFood();
    }

    let oldSnakeX = snakeX;
    let oldSnakeY = snakeY;

    // Update the positions of the segments in the snake's body
    if(velocityX != 0 || velocityY !=0){
        for (let i = snakeBody.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
        snakeBody[i] = snakeBody[i-1];
    }
        if (snakeBody.length) {
        snakeBody[0] = [oldSnakeX, oldSnakeY];
    }
}
    // update snake position based on velocity
    snakeX += velocityX * blockSize;
    snakeY += velocityY * blockSize;

    // update velocity based on current direction
    if (currentDirection == "up" && velocityY != 1) {
        velocityX = 0;
        velocityY = -1;
    }
    else if (currentDirection == "down" && velocityY != -1) {
        velocityX = 0;
        velocityY = 1;
    }
    else if (currentDirection == "left" && velocityX != 1) {
        velocityX = -1;
        velocityY = 0;
    }
    else if (currentDirection == "right" && velocityX != -1) {
        velocityX = 1;
        velocityY = 0;
    }


    // Draw the snake and its body segments
    ctx.fillStyle= snakeClr;
    ctx.strokeStyle = borderClr;
    ctx.fillRect(snakeX, snakeY, blockSize, blockSize);
    ctx.strokeRect(snakeX, snakeY, blockSize, blockSize);
    for (let i = 0; i < snakeBody.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillRect(snakeBody[i][0], snakeBody[i][1], blockSize, blockSize);
        ctx.strokeRect(snakeBody[i][0], snakeBody[i][1], blockSize, blockSize)
    } 

  
    // If the snake goes out of bounds, end the game
    if (snakeX < 0 || snakeX >= cols*blockSize || snakeY < 0 || snakeY >= rows*blockSize) {
        gameOver = true;
        displayGameover();
    }

    // If the snake collides with its body, end the game
    for (let i = 0; i < snakeBody.length; i++) {
        if (snakeX == snakeBody[i][0] && snakeY == snakeBody[i][1]) {
            gameOver = true;
            displayGameover();
        }
    }

    // This function displays the "Game Over" message
    function displayGameover(){
        ctx.font = "75px Courier New";
        ctx.fillStyle = foodClr;
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillText("Game Over!", board.height / 2, board.width / 2);
    }
}

// This function changes the direction of the snake based on user input
function changeDirection(e) {
    if (e.code == "ArrowLeft" && currentDirection == null){
        return;
    }
    if (e.code == "ArrowUp" && currentDirection != "down") {
        currentDirection = "up";
    }
    else if (e.code == "ArrowDown" && currentDirection != "up") {
        currentDirection = "down";
    }
    else if (e.code == "ArrowLeft" && currentDirection != "right") {
        currentDirection = "left";
    }
    else if (e.code == "ArrowRight" && currentDirection != "left") {
        currentDirection = "right";
    }
}
// This function places the food in a random position on the game board
function placeFood() {
    let foodPosValid = false; // Set foodPosValid to false initially
    while (!foodPosValid) { // Loop until a valid position is found for the food
    // Choose a random x and y position for the food
    foodX = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols) * blockSize;
    foodY = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows) * blockSize;
    foodPosValid = true; // Assume the position is valid
    // Check if the food position is already occupied by the snake
    for (let i = 0; i < snakeBody.length; i++) { 
        // If it is, set foodPosValid to false and break out of the loop
        if (snakeBody[i][0] == foodX && snakeBody[i][1] == foodY){
            foodPosValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
}


// This function restarts the game when the user clicks the button
restart.addEventListener("click", restartGame); 
function restartGame(){// Reset the score and snake variables, place food in a random position, set gameOver to false
    score = 0;
    snakeBody = [
        [snakeX - blockSize, snakeY],
        [snakeX  - 2 * blockSize, snakeY],
    ];
    snakeX = 5 * blockSize;
    snakeY = 5 * blockSize;
    velocityX = 0;
    velocityY = 0;
    currentDirection = null;
    placeFood();
    gameOver = false;
};


// This function toggles between the dark and light themes of the weebsite
function themeSwap(){
    document.documentElement.classList.toggle("darkmode");
    document.querySelectorAll(".inverted").forEach((result) => {
        result.classList.toggle("invert");
    });
};
const sitetheme = document.querySelector("#theme");
sitetheme.addEventListener("click", themeSwap);
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any errors in `restartGame()` function after adding these variable declarations:

```js
const board = document.getElementById("board");
const scoreTxt = document.getElementById("score");
const restart = document.getElementById("restart");
```

and the HTML looks like this:

```html
<h1>Snack Game</h1>
<canvas id="board"></canvas>
<p>Score: <span id="score">0</span></p>
<button id="restart">Restart</button>
<button id="theme">Theme</button>
```

Full code:

```js
//board
const blockSize = 25;
const rows = 20;
const cols = 20;
const board = document.getElementById("board"); // new
const scoreTxt = document.getElementById("score"); // new
const restart = document.getElementById("restart"); // new
const ctx = board.getContext("2d"); 
const borderClr = 'black';
const boardClr = 'green';

//snake
let snakeX = 5 * blockSize;
let snakeY = 5 * blockSize;


let snakeBody = [
    [snakeX - blockSize, snakeY],
    [snakeX  - 2 * blockSize, snakeY],
];

const snakeClr = 'blue';

// starting velocity
let velocityX = 0;
let velocityY = 0;

// current direction (only used to prevent changing direction multiple times with in one "tick")
let currentDirection = null;

//food
let radius = blockSize / 2;
let foodX;
let foodY;
const foodClr = "red";

let gameOver = false;

//score
let score = 0;
let gameSpeed = 100;

let intervalID;

// This function executes after the window has loaded
window.onload = function() {
    // Initialize the game board and set its dimensions
    board;
    board.height = rows * blockSize;
    board.width = cols * blockSize;
    // Initialize the canvas
    ctx;
    
    // Place the food on the board
    placeFood();
    // Listen for user input to change the direction of the snake
    document.addEventListener("keyup", changeDirection);
     // Set the update function to execute every 100 milliseconds
    intervalID = setInterval(update, gameSpeed);
    alert("Use arrow keys to move the snake.");
}

// This function updates the game state every time it is called
function update() {
    // If the game is over, stop updating
    if (gameOver) {
        return;
    }

    // Update the score display
    scoreTxt.textContent = score;
    
    // Clear the canvas and draw the board and food
    ctx.fillStyle= boardClr;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, board.width, board.height);


    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc( foodX + blockSize/2, foodY + blockSize/2, radius, 2 * Math.PI, 0, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = foodClr;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle = borderClr;
    ctx.stroke();

    // If the snake eats the food, increase the score and add a new segment to the snake
    if (snakeX == foodX && snakeY == foodY) {
        score += 1;
        snakeBody.push([foodX, foodY]);
        placeFood();
    }

    let oldSnakeX = snakeX;
    let oldSnakeY = snakeY;

    // Update the positions of the segments in the snake's body
    if(velocityX != 0 || velocityY !=0){
        for (let i = snakeBody.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
        snakeBody[i] = snakeBody[i-1];
    }
        if (snakeBody.length) {
        snakeBody[0] = [oldSnakeX, oldSnakeY];
    }
}
    // update snake position based on velocity
    snakeX += velocityX * blockSize;
    snakeY += velocityY * blockSize;

    // update velocity based on current direction
    if (currentDirection == "up" && velocityY != 1) {
        velocityX = 0;
        velocityY = -1;
    }
    else if (currentDirection == "down" && velocityY != -1) {
        velocityX = 0;
        velocityY = 1;
    }
    else if (currentDirection == "left" && velocityX != 1) {
        velocityX = -1;
        velocityY = 0;
    }
    else if (currentDirection == "right" && velocityX != -1) {
        velocityX = 1;
        velocityY = 0;
    }


    // Draw the snake and its body segments
    ctx.fillStyle= snakeClr;
    ctx.strokeStyle = borderClr;
    ctx.fillRect(snakeX, snakeY, blockSize, blockSize);
    ctx.strokeRect(snakeX, snakeY, blockSize, blockSize);
    for (let i = 0; i < snakeBody.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillRect(snakeBody[i][0], snakeBody[i][1], blockSize, blockSize);
        ctx.strokeRect(snakeBody[i][0], snakeBody[i][1], blockSize, blockSize)
    } 

  
    // If the snake goes out of bounds, end the game
    if (snakeX < 0 || snakeX >= cols*blockSize || snakeY < 0 || snakeY >= rows*blockSize) {
        gameOver = true;
        displayGameover();
    }

    // If the snake collides with its body, end the game
    for (let i = 0; i < snakeBody.length; i++) {
        if (snakeX == snakeBody[i][0] && snakeY == snakeBody[i][1]) {
            gameOver = true;
            displayGameover();
        }
    }

    // This function displays the "Game Over" message
    function displayGameover(){
        ctx.font = "75px Courier New";
        ctx.fillStyle = foodClr;
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillText("Game Over!", board.height / 2, board.width / 2);
    }
}

// This function changes the direction of the snake based on user input
function changeDirection(e) {
    if (e.code == "ArrowLeft" && currentDirection == null){
        return;
    }
    if (e.code == "ArrowUp" && currentDirection != "down") {
        currentDirection = "up";
    }
    else if (e.code == "ArrowDown" && currentDirection != "up") {
        currentDirection = "down";
    }
    else if (e.code == "ArrowLeft" && currentDirection != "right") {
        currentDirection = "left";
    }
    else if (e.code == "ArrowRight" && currentDirection != "left") {
        currentDirection = "right";
    }
}
// This function places the food in a random position on the game board
function placeFood() {
    let foodPosValid = false; // Set foodPosValid to false initially
    while (!foodPosValid) { // Loop until a valid position is found for the food
    // Choose a random x and y position for the food
    foodX = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols) * blockSize;
    foodY = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows) * blockSize;
    foodPosValid = true; // Assume the position is valid
    // Check if the food position is already occupied by the snake
    for (let i = 0; i < snakeBody.length; i++) { 
        // If it is, set foodPosValid to false and break out of the loop
        if (snakeBody[i][0] == foodX && snakeBody[i][1] == foodY){
            foodPosValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
}


// This function restarts the game when the user clicks the button
restart.addEventListener("click", restartGame); 
function restartGame(){// Reset the score and snake variables, place food in a random position, set gameOver to false
    score = 0;
    snakeBody = [
        [snakeX - blockSize, snakeY],
        [snakeX  - 2 * blockSize, snakeY],
    ];
    snakeX = 5 * blockSize;
    snakeY = 5 * blockSize;
    velocityX = 0;
    velocityY = 0;
    currentDirection = null;
    placeFood();
    gameOver = false;
};


// This function toggles between the dark and light themes of the weebsite
function themeSwap(){
    document.documentElement.classList.toggle("darkmode");
    document.querySelectorAll(".inverted").forEach((result) => {
        result.classList.toggle("invert");
    });
};
const sitetheme = document.querySelector("#theme");
sitetheme.addEventListener("click", themeSwap);
```

```html
<h1>Snack Game</h1>
<canvas id="board"></canvas>
<p>Score: <span id="score">0</span></p>
<button id="restart">Restart</button>
<button id="theme">Theme</button>
```

Comment: When you press restart after moving from the starting position the snake respawns with only head showing even though the real lenght is head + 2 segments.

Comment: Solved it myself. That solution was as simple as moving the snakeX and snakeY declarations above the snakeBody array on the resetGame function.